# How do I create a clone of the following array rather than a reference?

Tags: javascript

The code (a simple replace loop):

```
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err

  data = data.split('\n\n')
  var tree = data

  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
    if (tree[i].match(/^#/g)) {
      data[i] = data[i]
        .replace(/^#### (.*)/gm, '<h4>$1</h4>')
        .replace(/^### (.*)/gm, '<h3>$1</h3>')
        .replace(/^## (.*)/gm, '<h2>$1</h2>')
        .replace(/^# (.*)/gm, '<h1>$1</h1>')
    }
  }

  data = data.join('\n\n')
  tree = tree.join('\n\n')

  console.log(data)
  console.log(tree)
```

So in this case both `data` and `tree` have the same output:

```
<h1>Test</h1>

<h2>Test</h2>

Lorem "**ipsum?**" dolor 'sit!' amet

Anooo

* * *

"Ipsum?" "'**dolor**'" *sit!* amet, consetetur
eirmod tempor--invidunt **ut** labore

Anothes
```

What I want to do is to preserve the original value of `data` in `tree` so that only `data` changes but not `tree`.

How to do that?

`tree` should remain like this:

```
# Test

## Test

Lorem "**ipsum?**" dolor 'sit!' amet

Anooo

* * *

"Ipsum?" "'**dolor**'" *sit!* amet, consetetur
eirmod tempor--invidunt **ut** labore

Anothes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

`The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.`

`var tree = data.slice();`

Answer (score 3):

Use a hack

```
var tree = data.slice(0)
```

It may be wrapped to a separate function/method.

Comment: `data.slice()` may be used (without arguments) as in Rodrigo Assis's answer

Answer (score 2):

Jquery

```
var newObj = obj.extend({}, obj)
```

AngularJS

```
var newObj = angular.copy(obj)
```

Plain javascript

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```